# Slide down from the Top effect not working on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am expecting that one of my button will work and pop out these forms, but every time I hit the button "More" nothing happens. Please help!

```
<body>
    <!--Hero Image-->
    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1 id="demo">Hi! I'm Jake</h1>
            <p>Webby web</p>

        <!-- The overlay -->
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">

          <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

          <!-- Overlay content -->
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu-->
        <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please may your remove the comment and edit the question instead?

Comment: you need to provide more context what are you trying to achieve exactly and where is the problem

Comment: @JakeAngeloVargas If you are using bootstrap or any other fe toolkit please specify in the description. Also if you reproduce the behavior on codesandobx or elsewhere it would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the wrong CSS property in your JavaScript. It should be `display`, not `height`. See, for example:

```js
document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";

function displayNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!--Hero Image-->
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 id="demo">Hi! I'm Jake</h1>
    <p>Webby web</p>

    <!-- The overlay -->
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">

      <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <!-- Overlay content -->
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu-->
    <button class="button" onclick="displayNav()">More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I cannot upvote your answer I need atleast 15 reputation :( but I really appreciate your answer.